# what is the page write buffer of this memory FRAM?

Tags: memory, eeprom

can someone tell me which is the page write buffer of this memory fram [MB85RC256V](https://www.fujitsu.com/us/Images/MB85RC256V-DS501-00017-3v0-E.pdf)

is it 32Kbyte ?

Answer (score -1):

This device doesn't have a page write buffer: it is capable of writing individual bytes as fast as you can send them, so no buffering is needed.

Buffer size is something you have to worry about on much slower memory devices, such as EEPROM, that need many milliseconds to do an erase/write cycle.  Devices with a write buffer are capable of writing multiple bytes in that same time - but it's entirely your responsibility to make sure that all the bytes fit in the same page.  Crossing a page boundary in the middle of a write is likely to result in some data being written to the wrong address.

Comment: but, what about page write is much faster than byte faster. Also I can see arduino wire.h library has a limit buffer to 30 bytes only